# Audio play() not responding in create-react-app componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, audio

I created a create-react-app project I manage to  import jquery as $ and use I in the componentDidMount() lifecycle hook,

In the render() method I have

```
audio ref="bgAudio"
   source src={this.state.bgAudio}
```

the state

```
this.state{ bgAudio:"./bgAudio.mp3" }
```

I want to invoke the audio  file to play 1 when the page loaded .. as a background music, I tried using

```
componentDidMount(){
 this.refs.bgAudio.play();
}
```

but it seams the

```
play();
```

function is not working

P.S. I'm making it as a game. Also, i have a  few buttons that onClick execute a function .. I  would like if you give me an advice how to play sounds on click as well. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to play a background sound, you don't to use `componentDidMount()`. `<audio>` allow us to do it in declarative way, using these both attributes:

- `autoPlay`: the song will play when mounted.
- `loop`: the song will loop when finished.

Example:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <audio src={ audioURL } loop autoPlay />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: I just edited my answer to give you a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

try following this is a code snippet I create for another answer might help you. In this code audio plays when page loaded you can stop it by clicking a button

```js
//music
var audio = new Audio('http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3')
checksound();



function checksound() {

var myElement = document.getElementById("soundMenu");
  myElement.innerHTML = "Turn Sound " + (audio.paused ? "OFF" : "ON");

  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
  } else {
    audio.pause();
  }

}

function myFunction() {


var myElement = document.getElementById("soundMenu");
  myElement.innerHTML = "Turn Sound " + (audio.paused ? "OFF" : "ON");

  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
  } else {
    audio.pause();
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="soundMenu" onclick="checksound()">Play</button>
<input type="text" onkeypress="myFunction()" />
```

Comment: @AkhilAravind it because of the sound file, use this and replace with you sound file